# Extract a list from the request body sent to FastAPI application

Tags: python, fastapi, pydantic

I have a FastAPI application which makes a prediction based on the HTTP POST data sent to it. The code is as follows

```
import tensorflow as tf
from typing import List
from fastapi import FastAPI, Response
from pydantic import BaseModel

class ItemList(BaseModel):
    instances: List[List[float]]

app = FastAPI()

model = tf.keras.models.load_model('trainedmodel/1')

@app.post('/v1/models/my_model:predict')
def predict(inputdata: ItemList):
    # Extract [[1.5,1.65,2,0.5,-2,1.5,0.1,2,0.2]]
    result = {
                 "predictions": [
                         model.predict(modelInput).flatten().tolist()
                 ]
    }
    return result
```

The request type to the application is application/json and the request body contains `{"instances":[[1.5,1.65,2,0.5,-2,1.5,0.1,2,0.2]]}`

I need to extract `[[1.5,1.65,2,0.5,-2,1.5,0.1,2,0.2]]` from the request body so that I can input it to the model (as `modelInput` in the above code). In Flask I used `request.json['instances']` to do so. Can someone please let me know how I can do the same in FastAPI?

Comment: just `inputdata.instances`

Comment: Thank you @AlexNoname! It worked. I remember trying this earlier and it failed. Probably because I had an error somewhere else. 
Can you add this as an answer so that I can accept it as the best answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To access request body you can just use `inputdata.instances`

```py
class ItemList(BaseModel):
    instances: List[List[float]]

@app.post('/v1/models/my_model:predict')
def predict(inputdata: ItemList):
    # Extract [[1.5,1.65,2,0.5,-2,1.5,0.1,2,0.2]]
    extracted_list = inputdata.instances
```

Comment: Hi! I'm trying to do the same thing but I have a problem. I want to predict a list of items, but I don't know how send a list of items to requests.post function since apparently it only accepts json. I'm really new to this whole deploying model thing, so any help is appreciated!

Comment: @Tata could you solve your problem? I'm experiencing the exact same thing.